# NSFileWriteNoPermissionError when trying to create a new directory in /Library/Application Support/

Tags: cocoa, permissions, directory, nsfilemanager

The following code returns a NSCocoaErrorDomain with error code 513 (NSFileWriteNoPermissionError) when running from xcode.

```
NSError *error;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
createDirectoryAtPath:@"/Library/Application Support/myapp" 
withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
attributes:nil 
error:&error];
```

This is on a Mac OS X 10.6.7, the specified directory does not exist, and my user has admin privileges.

The purpose is to save application support files that are shared among users. Shouldn't there be write permissions to create this directory?

Answer (score 3):

No, that's the system's Library folder. You need the user's Library, at "~/Library/". You could try:

```
[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Application Support/myapp"]
```

or:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * appSupportPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myapp"];
```

Just for one more option, you can also get a URL from the file manager:

```
NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray * urls = [fm URLsForDirectory:NApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL * appSupportURL = [urls objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Well, it is an 'Application Support' directory, so I don't see why my application couldn't use it.  Plus, I see plenty of folders from other applications that I've installed on my mac in there.  Also, the idea is that I want to save files that are shared among users, so that is why I don't use the ~/Library/Application Support directory.

Comment: @user497804: The user, even if an admin, doesn't own /Library, and so your app can't write there without getting authorization, which is usually done by popping up a dialog asking the user to authenticate. I think that you'll need to look into [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1).